# Spring Boot health checks for non-web apps

Tags: spring, spring-boot

After reading up on the Spring Boot Actuator features, specifically the health endpoint, I've found it quite useful for implementing docker container health checks for some of my services.

However some of my services are not webapps, and it seems like overkill to enable HTTP just to allow the container to check the app is up and running. Looking through the options, actuator seems to support HTTP endpoints, JMX, and SSH/Telnet, though that last one apparently requires you to be running a JDK, and is going away in boot 2.0.

Are there any established ways of doing container healthchecks for non-web spring boot apps?

Comment: There are different ways of doing container healthchecks. Have a look at this repo [docker-healthcheck](https://github.com/docker-library/healthcheck) .